# How to read binary data stored in NSData

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am getting data from a web call. Here is data.

> 00000001 00045043 4c4e0000 00023744 92f4cd44 92f4cd44 92f4cd44 92f4cd3c a3d70a00 00014de2 b767a044 93800044 93800044 93800044 93800040 a0000000 00014de2 bdd04044 94400044 94400044 93db3344 94170a3f a6666600 00014de2 c8ccc044 93ddc344 93ddc344 93ddc344 93ddc33e 99999a00 00014de2 ce4b0044 93bd1f44 943d7144 9394cd44 93eccd41 e8e14800 00014de2 d01fc044 93eb3344 93eb3344 93b00044 93b00040 c0000000

The data format is fixed (We know where it stores int / float etc.

Question is how do I read and store it in individual variables
For example the first 4 bytes here are specifying the number of symbols returned (1)

Comment: This cannot be answered without knowing the spec. Do you have that?

Comment: Basically i Know that first 4 bytes are integer than I have 2 bytes short, then 4 byte string and so on...Does that help?

Comment: What is the endianness of the ints/floats/etc?

Comment: The data is coming from Ameritrade APIs. The spec was not very detailed. hence I had to reverse engineer it. Basically reading individual integers, shorts, floats and strings from the raw binary data. For example, to read the int I have

Comment: NSMutableString *stringHexForm = [NSMutableString string];
for(int i = startLocation ; i < (startLocation + nCharsToReadIn) ; i++)
{
        unsigned char byte;        
        [dataIn getBytes : &byte range : NSMakeRange(i, 1)];        
        NSString *tempStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02x",byte];        
        [stringHexForm appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",tempStr]]; }
    
unsigned result = 0;    

    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner  stringHexForm];

    [scanner scanHexInt:&result];

    return result;

Comment: So, we can close this question now

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableString *stringHexForm = [NSMutableString string];

for(int i = startLocation ; i < (startLocation + nCharsToReadIn) ; i++)
{
    unsigned char byte;

    [dataIn getBytes : &byte range : NSMakeRange(i, 1)];

    NSString *tempStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02x",byte];

    [stringHexForm appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",tempStr]];
}

unsigned result = 0;    

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner  stringHexForm];

[scanner scanHexInt:&result];

return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

NSData has the method `func getBytes(buffer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, range: NSRange)` that should help you. You can grab each thing in your struct by specifying the range.

So you can do:

```
var length: Int = 0
myData.getBytes(&length, range: NSMakeRange(0, 4))
```

and so on for each type, range that you need

Comment: I read the first 4 bytes [0] = '\0', [1] = '\0', [2] = '\0', [3] = '\x01' in a byte array. But how do I convert these 4 bytes to give me Integer 1. I tried NSScanner scanHexInt..No Luck